# Как сейчас верстают под IE 9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Появилось требование весь сайт который изначально вообще не задумывался для IE 9 оптимизировать и под него тоже. Все Flex'ы и Grid'ы можно выбросить я так понимаю. Существуют ли сейчас какие-то автопрефиксеры для IE 9 и как сейчас вообще посмотреть как выглядит сайт на IE 9? Пока искал ссылки, половина не работает, половина сайтов (которые заявляют бесплатными в прошлых годах) сейчас просят подписку. Отмечать буду все "фишки" для работы с этим браузером.

Comment: Никак. Зачем верстать под IE 9 в 2021 году?

Comment: Я полностью согласен, что это абсурд. Но так вышло, что до сих пор в каких-нибудь офисах на древних ПК стоит IE, в лучшем случае 9. И в заказах такие условия проявляются порой. Отсюда и вопрос возник.

Comment: https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility можете попробовать этот полифилл для поддержки флексбоксов, но он уже 3 года без комитов, поэтому не факт что заработает

Comment: Вот так - [Как помочь посетителю сайта обновить свой браузер?](https://yandex.ru/dev/browser/constructor/doc/index.html#generate)

Comment: Что тут думать? Намутить приблизительно сайт из параграфов, таблиц и картинок ака версия для печати и поставить перед фактом, что это максимум. _Минимальная_ связка на сегодняшний момент - это WinXP+Chrome49.

Comment: А вообще не нужно искать ссылки, нужно ставить Windows 7 в виртуальную машину, в ней ставить IE 9 и тестировать сайт без всяких внешних сервисов. (Но лучше всего конечно отказаться от поддержки IE)

Comment: А есть ли возможность вызова попап окна если человек с IE 9 и меньше, например? Как думаете на сколько актуально вызывать окно по типу "Мы обнаружили, что Ваш браузер устарел и требует обновлений. Некоторые элементы могут отображаться некорректно". Ну и например ссылки на скачивание ряда браузеров хром/мозила/яндекс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shiv html5 вам в помощь, а также условия if IE, в них можно подключить другой CSS, где будет все сверстано на float

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js" integrity="sha512-UDJtJXfzfsiPPgnI5S1000FPLBHMhvzAMX15I+qG2E2OAzC9P1JzUwJOfnypXiOH7MRPaqzhPbBGDNNj7zBfoA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<![endif]-->
```